# HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender

Tags: spring-ws, hostname

We are using `spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar` for spring web service connections. In order to bypass/override invalid host (source and sender are not the same) for testing purposes, I am trying to do this:

```
public void setWebServicesTemplate(WebServicesTemplate template) {
   HostnameVerifier verifier = new NullHostnameVerifier();
   HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender sender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
   sender.setHostnameVerifier(verifier);
   template.setMessageSender(sender);
   this.template = template;
}
public class NullHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
   public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
      return true;
   }
}
```

I am not able to find this class in my version of `spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar`, however I am able to see it in the previous and higher versions of the .jar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following dependency as this class is part of spring-ws-support:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```